# How to create a 2D map with kinect sensor?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner in ROS. I don't have a laser so I have been trying to create map with kinect sensor. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out where I am going wrong. I tried using depth_image to laser_scan but to no avail, it is not converting the image to scan. I am using freenect. I can see pointcloud data from the kinect in rviz in real time and I am stuck there. Can anyone help me out with a tutorial or some points I have to follow step by step?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237535/how-to-create-a-2d-map-with-kinect-sensor?/) by [ros_beginner101](https://answers.ros.org/users/27226/ros_beginner101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
I think navigation stack tutorial will help you to understand what you need
http://wiki.ros.org/navigation
and remember you need odometery data you can git it from encoder and imu
this tutorial must help you to understand what you need to do.

---

Originally posted by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) with karma: 89 on 2016-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_beginner101](https://answers.ros.org/users/27226/ros_beginner101/) on 2016-06-29**:
Thanks ghaith, I am reading navigation stack. Hope you don't mind if I get back to you if I stuck again.

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-29**:
no problem